¿Cómo hacer un dropdown search para filtrar resultados de una base de datos? MySQL, JSP
Espero que tengan un buen día. Lo que pasa es que estoy en un proyecto que involucra un uso de MySQL con Java Web (Según mi Netbeans mi proyecto usa Jakarta EE 10). Tengo un combobox que trae una lista de usuarios correctamente. El problema es que no sé cómo podría agregar un cuadro de búsqueda en ese mismo combobox para filtrar esos resultados (si es posible en tiempo real). Es decir un dropdown search que al escribir el nombre de un usuario los resultados vayan reduciéndose hasta encontrar el usuario específico. Aquí paso el código de cómo está el formulario como tal el cuál si trae los usuarios correctamente en mi proyecto. Solo necesito una idea general de cómo podría hacer para agregarle una búsqueda para filtrar los usuarios. Adjunto tanto un tutorial que he seguido como la sección específica del formulario que trae los usuarios de la base de datos MySQL.
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="idUsuario" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar Usuario</option>
                        <% 
                            PreparedStatement psUsuarios2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT IdUsuario, Nombres FROM Usuario WHERE EstadoRegistro = 1");
                            ResultSet rsUsuarios2 = psUsuarios2.executeQuery();
                            while (rsUsuarios2.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%= rsUsuarios2.getInt("IdUsuario") %>"><%= rsUsuarios2.getString("Nombres") %></option>
                        <% } rsUsuarios2.close(); psUsuarios2.close(); %>
                    </select>
                </div>
                


Supongo que usando jquery y el plugin Select2 te podria valer, pero ni idea de jsp o java web, supongo que viene a ser lo mismo, una página web al final.
